What does it mean for CMake to find a "pthread-compatible" library?
CMake's FindThreads script documentation says that the variable CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS_INIT will be set "if the found thread library is pthread compatible."
What does that mean? If it's an actual POSIX threads implementation, then obviously it's "pthread compatible"; but what are other "compatible" threads libraries? And what assumptions can I make about them? To take the most basic example: Can I safely include <pthread.h>?

tl;dr: "pthread-compatible" means you can assume it's good old pthreads.
(Looking at the FindThreads.cmake source (as of CMake 3.28.3), the answer seems to be:)
This flag will be set if any of the following two conditions hold:

Your system has library called pthread or pthreads you can link against; or
The following C program build successfully:
#include <pthread.h>

static void* test_func(void* data)
{
  return data;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t thread;
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, test_func, NULL);
  pthread_detach(thread);
  pthread_cancel(thread);
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, NULL);
  pthread_exit(NULL);

  return 0;
}



In the second case you know exactly what's going on, so no problems there. The first case is a bit of a leap of faith, since you haven't checked exactly what that library is - but then, so are many other library tests; you usually accept that a library calling itself foo is indeed the libfoo you are looking for.
